# file images not detected

Tags: python, face-recognition

i'm doing my first face recognition project.

i have images data which will be encoded, so this is my list of my directory

```
./dataset/person1/images.jpg
./dataset/person2/images.jpg
```

and this is my code:

```
import face_recognition
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

path = './dataset'
folders = [f for f in glob.glob(path +'**/*', recursive=True)

for f in folders:
    print(f)
    for images_file in glob.glob('*.jpg'):
        #the encoding code will be right here
        print(images_file)
```

when i run the code, i got the output the list of my directory:

```
'./dataset/person1'
'./dataset/person2'
```

i think my code just run the `print(f)` function.

why my `print(images_file)` code not running?  does it not read the images file from the subdirectory of dataset? i need help.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You're not using `f` in the glob with jpgs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import face_recognition
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

path = './dataset'
folders = [f for f in glob.glob(path +'**/*', recursive=True)]

cv_img = []
for images_file in folders:
    n= cv2.imread(images_file)
    cv_img.append(n)

#the encoding code will be right here ->
# use cv_img list to write your encoding code
print(cv_img)
```